# how to export table into flat file with different name in mysql?

Tags: mysql, export, export-to-csv, into-outfile

I am exporting a table using -

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'd:\\result.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY  '\n'
FROM result;
```

Now I want to run this script daily by putting it in procedure. And I want use file name "result" with date or some other dynamic number which i can increase daily. Otherwise it will give me error for the duplicate file name.

I should be like -

```
declare var_result varchar(100);
set var_result = 'result01012014';
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE var_result
................................
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating `Stored Procedure` You can create a `shell or php` script for the same

Example of a shell script that I usually use

```
#!/bin/bash

location="/home/abdul/Desktop"
user="root"
pass="root"
table="City"
database="world_innodb"

mysql -u$user -p$pass --column-names -e "SELECT * FROM $database.$table;" | sed 's/\t/"|"/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g' > $location/$table-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").csv
```

This will create file name like `City-2014-02-20.csv`

Stored procedure to do the same

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ExportToCSV;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `ExportToCSV`()

    BEGIN
    SET @cur_date =  CURRENT_DATE();
    SET @path = "/tmp/";
    SET @table_name =  "City";

    SET @VarSQL = CONCAT('SELECT * INTO OUTFILE  \'' ,@path,@table_name,'-',@cur_date,'.csv\' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''\,','\' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY \'','"' ,'\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'','\\n','\' FROM ',@table_name,';' );

    PREPARE stmt FROM @VarSQL;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: this is helpful,but i want to do this using above technique. So please me let me if there is any way to sort this out.