# mysql stored procedure with INTO OUTFILE

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a mysql stored procedure where I want to do two things
1. query a table and return the result as normal result set.
2. iterate through the result set and create a formatted text file from the procedure itself.

I looked at INTO OUTFILE, but it seems INTO OUTFILE writes the result raw to the specified file and also if we use INTO OUTFILE resultset will be empty. Seems we can't have both.

Here is my sample SP

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getdeals`()
BEGIN

select * INTO OUTFILE '/Users/tuser/sql/out.txt' from deals;

END
```

Any thoughts ?
Thanks
Prem

Comment: Have a look my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21909024/792290

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming (*for the sake of the example*) that your `deals` table looks like

```
---------------------------
| id | deal_date  | deal  |
---------------------------
| 1  | 2014-03-10 | Deal1 |
| 2  | 2014-03-11 | Deal2 |
| 3  | 2014-03-12 | Deal3 |
---------------------------
```

Now your procedure code might look

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE get_deals()
BEGIN
    -- create a temporary table and fill it with the desired subset of data
    -- Apply WHERE and ORDER BY as needed
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_deals;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_deals 
    SELECT id, deal_date, deal -- explicitly specify real column names here. Don't use SELECT *. It's a bad practice.
      FROM deals
     ORDER BY id DESC;

    -- write the resultset to the file
    SELECT * 
      INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/deals.txt'
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
      FROM tmp_deals;

    -- return the resultset to the client
    SELECT * FROM tmp_deals; 
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

After executing it:

```sql
CALL get_deals();
```

On the client you'll get:

```
---------------------------
| id | deal_date  | deal  |
---------------------------
| 3  | 2014-03-12 | Deal3 |
| 2  | 2014-03-11 | Deal2 |
| 1  | 2014-03-10 | Deal1 |
---------------------------
```

And the file contents will be:

```
3,"2014-03-12","Deal3"
2,"2014-03-11","Deal2"
1,"2014-03-10","Deal1"
```

**Note:** when using `OUTFILE` MySQL requires that the file should be created **afresh**. If you leave the file in the output directory then on the subsequent procedure call you'll get the following error

> File '/path/to/deals.txt' already exists

One way to workaround it is by appending a timestamp to the filename either within the procedure itself or by passing a value through a parameter.

Comment: i have concluded this and this works. Was thinking about a duplicate sql call overhead. but i will settle for this :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$

SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(conSTR);

string sql = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/Users/tuser/sql/out.txt' FROM deals";
connection.Open();
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, connection);
SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds=new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
//datagridview1 is name of datagridview in form:
datagridview1.DataSource=ds.Tables[0];
connection.Close();
```

Will that work for you?

Comment: I am not sure whether this will work. In my scenario I am calling the procedure from Java and I want to get the result set in Java AND save the results to a file from the Procedure. Basically return the result to Java layer AND save the result in a file from the stored procedure.  Thoughts ?

Comment: That's the best shot I had sorry... I voted it up so  hopefully you will get some more advice

Comment: Np. Thanks for the try!