# How to create a .txt file and insert data into it in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, file

I'm learning about triggers and events and I have the following issue:

I have created a trigger that inserts data in a table called `updated_movie` when an update is made in table `movie`.

Also, I want to create an event that executes every day at 11:30am that creates a text file with some data from the table `updated_movie`. I have made this so far:

```
delimiter !!
drop event if exists createFile !!
create event createFile on schedule at "11:30"

do begin

    declare path varchar(255) default "/Users/Shared/BDD/L19/";
    declare nameFile varchar(255) default curdate();
    declare done int default 0;
    declare t varchar(255);

    -- creation of the text file?

    declare c cursor for select title from updated_movie;
    declare continue handler for not found set done = 1;

    open c;

    l:loop
        fetch c into t;

        if done = 1 then
            leave l;
        end if;

        call copyIntoFile(t, nameFile);

    end loop l;

end!!

delimiter ;
```

This is the event I want to be executed every day. How can I create a text file into the path declared in the event with the same file name as the declared variable `nameFile`?

Also, procedure `copyIntoFile` looks like this so far:

```
delimiter !!
drop procedure if exists copyIntoFile !!
create procedure copyIntoFile(in str varchar(255), in fileName varchar(255)

begin

    -- Copy into the text file?

end !!

delimiter ;
```

How can I make it so I can insert some data into the text field?

In case that you are wondering, table `updated_movie` just have one `varchar(255)` field.

Comment: Hey this could be a duplicate see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21253800/2408013 or better here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22342839/2408013

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql stored procedure with INTO OUTFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265517/mysql-stored-procedure-with-into-outfile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE EVENT createFile 
ON SCHEDULE 
    EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '11:30' HOUR_MINUTE
ENABLE
DO
SELECT *
    INTO OUTFILE 'drive:\\folder\\filename.ext'
    FROM updated_movie
    WHERE created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Modify conditions, output expressions, add export specifications if needed.

Check `secure_file_priv` setting and related ones, and justify destination forder accordingly. FILE privilege needed.

PS. BEGIN-END, DELIMITER, etc. - are excess.

Comment: Thanks! It may work. Now I have to figure out how to change `secure_file_priv` setting. I am using Mac and MySQLWorkbench, any help is welcome!

Comment: *I have to figure out how to change secure_file_priv setting* Edit INI file. Restart MySQL.